# how to do a @-webkit-keyframes drop with different heights

Tags: css, webkit, media-queries

I have this in my css file

```
/* Makes a leaf fall from -300 to 600 pixels in the y-axis */
@-webkit-keyframes drop
{
/* Move a leaf to -300 pixels in the y-axis at the start of the animation */
0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -50px); }
/* Move a leaf to 600 pixels in the y-axis at the end of the animation */
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 650px); }
```

}

How can I change the 650px to different sizes depending on screen height?

Comment: Media queries..You can use `height` in that too.

Comment: Yes but how do I write it, I am at the end of the day and cant think straight, so as a last resort thought I would ask for help.

Comment: http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/height-based-media-queries.php

Comment: Thats great for changing the color, which I knew, but how would I implement it to change the 650px, my mind is blank... maybe I need to sleep on it.

Comment: I know its probably simple but for the life of me, I cant figure out how to.